# In() using spring jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

i am new to **spring jdbc**.i am getting array index out of the box error while retrieving records from database.?can any give example for how to retrieve specific columns using IN()
this is my code:

```
public List<ProjectInfo> getAccounts(List<String> domains) { 
    List<ProjectInfo> accountList=new ArrayList<ProjectInfo>();
    String sql= "select * from dep_pid_exc where sub_vertical in(:verticals)";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate= new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    Map<String, List<String>> params= Collections.singletonMap("verticals",domains);
    accountList =jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new PCRowMapper(),params);
    return accountList;
}
```

i am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(PreparedStatement.java:3197)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:4338)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:3985)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:365)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:720)
at com.pc.dao.PCDaoImpl.getAccounts(PCDaoImpl.java:60)
at com.pc.services.PCServiceImpl.getAccounts(PCServiceImpl.java:17)
at com.pc.controllers.PCController.domainChange(PCController.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
```

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` doesn't have support for a dynamic IN clause and it certainly doesn't have support for named parameters. For this use the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. Performance tip, don't construct a `JdbcTemplate` each time you need one, create a single instance and reuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to name your parameters in your SQL query, you should then use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` spring class. See this [example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-named-parameter-jdbc-template.html) for more details.

And as far as I remember `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` is your only option for `IN` statements.